# Cancel key event in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

here is the thing.
I've a Swift application with a NSTextField. The user can edit the text inside and validate the change by typing the "enter" key on his keyboard.
However, the enter key is already used for an other action in my software.

How could I bypass my shortcut action for only validate the text?

I thought about using a flag regarding in which even we are but it's not the most elegant solution I think...

**Update**

The architecture is the following. The NSTextField is in a file and the other action comes from an other ViewController. The action is mad using the storyboard.
So the NSTextField cannot communicate easily (i.e without a lot of couplage) withe the action in the view controller.

Comment: Have a delegate for the textfield. As soon as the user enters the textfield, the delegates tells you, so at this time you can deactivate your other action. When the use leaves the textfield, you can reactivate your other action.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I added an update to my question because I cannot easily communicate between the textfield and the action. I may go to use a notification in the textfieldevent but how can you deactivate an action in cocoa? If it's not possible I will use a flag I think...

Comment: How does the view controller catch the enter key?

Comment: @Willeke I just create an `@IBAction` (drag and drop style) from the interface builder to my view controller

Comment: How did you connect the enter key to the action?

Comment: @Willeke oh sorry didn't understand your question. In the interface builder I use a simple `key equivalent`. I set this field to the enter key.

Comment: @Willeke I think I found. My `NSButton` has a field "keyEquivalent`. When I want to activate it, I use `keyEquivalent = "\n"`. To deactivate I use `keyEquivalent = ""`

Comment: @Willeke in fact my solution doesn't work. Let's say I edit the text and hit the enter key. My notification called the specific selector where I set the keyEquivalent to "\r". But the related event to the button is immediately called too...

Comment: I tried this (using the Return key, my keyboard doesn't have an Enter key) but first the validate method is called. If the value is valid, the action method of the button is called. How do you validate the value of the text field?

Comment: @Willeke I use the `controlTextDidEndEditing` delegate function to validate. But how do you enable/disable the button action method? I have a problem with this as you can see on my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46408413/2448287