# How to clear event in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I've a ViewController with a NSButton linked to a IBAction let's say `perform()`. The button is key equivalent to the return key.
However the return key is also used in for a other temporary action. In an other file no related to previous ViewController, I have a NSTextfield which is editable, so the return key would validate the text changes.

I would like to validate my text without firing `perform()` function called from the key equivalent button.

For the moment the only solution I found is to send a notification `textIsBeingEditing` when my text field becomeFirstResponder and an other when the delegate function `controlTextDidEndEditing`.

Here is the selector of my notification:

```
@objc func trackNameIsBeingEditedNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let value = notification.userInfo?["trackNameIsBeingEdited"]
      as? Bool else {
        return
    }

    if value {
      backButton.keyEquivalent = ""
      backButton.action = nil
    } else {
      myButton.keyEquivalent = "\r"
      myButton.action = #selector(self.perform(_:))
      // Here the `perform()` function is fired but I would avoid this behaviour…
    }
}
```

Isn't any way to cancel the key event in order to prevent `perform()` to be fired just after I set `myButton.action = #selector(self.perform(_:))` ?
I see a function called `flushBufferedKeyEvents()` but I totally doesn't know how to use it

Comment: continuation of [Cancel key event in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401695/cancel-key-event-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment79769275_46401695)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use notifications, use the delegate method `optional func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool` to validate the value of the text field.

Comment: This is the default and expected behaviour of a default button. Which control is focussed when the button should catch the key?

Comment: The focused control should be the `NSTextfiled` but I saw that when I clic on the `NSTextField` the function `becomeFirstResponder` is called and right after (i.e without doing anything) the function `resignFirstRespoinder` is also called. Is it normal?

Comment: Yes, this is normal. The field editor becomes the first responder.